# How can i add HTML input from C#, ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have this HTML table in my aspx page which will be populated from datatable, and I need to put a checkbox at the start of each row.
I tried to use the code below in which I used `StringBuilder` and I also tried using `TagBuilder` but nothing works.

```
//Building an HTML string.
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

//Building the Data rows.
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    html.Append("<tr>");

    html.Append("<td>");
    html.AppendFormat("< input type = 'checkbox' />"); //here it displays the tag as string
    html.Append("</td>");

    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<td>");
        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]); //here it displays the data
        html.Append("</td>");
    }
    html.Append("</tr>");

}
datatableBody.Controls.Add(new Literal
{
    Text = html.ToString()
});
```

Here is the Table :

```
<table class="table dataTable my-0" id="dataTable" style="text-align:center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>Matricule</th>
            <th>Prenom</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Periode</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="datatableBody" runat="server">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here are the results:

[image: image of the displayed result]

I also want to be able to access the value of the checkbox (checked or not).

Comment: Have you tried using `@Html.Raw()`?

Comment: Replace html.AppendFormat by html.Append

Comment: @MarwenJaffel Tried that, nothing changes.

Comment: @JamesS Can you provide more details. I searched for that and didn't come out with a result.

Comment: you can use HtmlTextWriter for adding html

Comment: `html.Append("<td> <a href='" + url + "?Val=" + item.ID + "' class='btn btn-success btn-lg' style='color:#000;'>Ok</a></td>");` in my case i used string builder to create table that contains <a></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about that but I think you can use something like this :

```
html.Append("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"CheckSelect").Append(row["id"]).Append("\">");
```

Or If you don't mind to use Jquery, here is a solution for you :

https://forums.asp.net/t/2156602.aspx?Appending+the+Checkbox+to+the+HTML+Table+